# wysiwyg for Heroku with Django and S3 static file hosting

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, cross-domain, wysiwyg

I have a django app running on Heroku, with my static files hosted to Amazon s3 using boto and django-storages, as seems to be standard procedure on here.

Setting these up so far has been troublesome, and I would like to avoid future cross-domain hassle as I am considering to install a wysiwyg editor, to make a sort of FAQ where users can ask questions and post answers.

Is there a better package than django-tinymce? I have across a number of users who have had trouble with this, as js static files need to be served locally from heroku. I would prefer something lightweight, as this is for a basic purpose.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Suit skin for Django admin, and one of the WYSIWYG options is something called Redactor. That's a quite nice-looking text editor that works well. It can sometimes produce a little garbage HTML but nothing too scary or malformed (just the odd empty `div` or `span`).

What you'll also probably want to do is use CloudFront to distribute your static and media files, and whitelist the `Origin` HTTP header. There are also some cross-domain rules you can add to your bucket.

My CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) settings are really bastardised form people who know more than I do, so if you want a clean approach I'd suggest checking the [Amazon docs on the subject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). They go through the details of setting all that up. This [simpler guide](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/cors-ie-cloudfront/) might also help, as it just goes into the basic CORS settings.

But I've got that running and so far haven't come up against any cross-domain issues.

Hope that helps.